# Statistically determine whether a set of variables are diverging

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm collecting data on a battery which is being discharged and charged again repeatedly. This battery consists of 4 cells in series and I am recording the fully-charged voltage of each cell at the end of every 10 cycles. Firstly, we know they are *not* initially at the exact same voltage (though close). Secondly, there is some uncertainty in what the fully-charged voltage will be due to equipment accuracy. Example:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Cycle Cell0  Cell1  Cell2  Cell3  |
+-----------------------------------+
| 0     4.149  4.1745 4.1715 4.1475 |
| 10    4.1205 4.1565 4.158  4.1325 |
| 20    4.155  4.179  4.191  4.1505 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I'm thinking about how to prove or disprove (statistically) this hypothesis:

> The voltage difference between cells is increasing with respect to
>   the original difference (ie at cycle 0).

I know that standard deviation will give me an idea of "how spread out" the cells are for a given cycle, and I can compute that for every cycle, and then fit a line to the list of standard deviations. But does that even make sense? I'm just thinking, if (for instance) the resulting slope is tiny, how can I be confident that the result is significant (ie not just a product of noise)?